# For loop is only posting first 3 elements of array - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have arrays which can potentially have unlimited amount of elements in them. I am trying to input them into my db but it only inputs the first 3 elements of the arrays. 
My arrays looks like this

```
array(4) {
  ["ID"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  ["firstname"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Steve"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Dan"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "Jim"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "Adam"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "James"
  }
  ["surname"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Colins"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Knight"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Lamar"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "Rays"
  }
  ["submit"]=>
  string(5) "Enter"
}
```

this is my for loop and sql statement

```
$a[0] = $_SESSION['ID'];
$a[1] = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$a[2] = $_SESSION['surname'];


 for ($i = 0; $i<count($a); ++$i){
     $id = $_SESSION['ID'][$i];
     $fname = $_SESSION['firstname'][$i];
     $sname = $_SESSION['surname'][$i];

$query = "INSERT INTO orders(id, firstname, surname) VALUES('$id', '$fname', '$sname')";


if (mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}
}
```

this will only post the 0,1,2 elements of each array. How can I change it so it insert all elements to my db?

Comment: You are looping through `$a`, which only has 3 visible entries.  Not sure where else it's supposed to get rows from to insert.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `$a` array? Other than the erroneous `count($a)`, you're never using it for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($a); ++$i)
```

This cycle will go three times because `$a` array has 3 items (ID, firstname, surname). Change `count($a)` to `count($a[0])` and it should work. Although this isn't exactly the best solution (what if one of those three arrays has more/less items than the others?...)

Comment: Thank you this should work because all arrays will have the same amount of elements

Comment: How can you be so sure? I suppose the array is input from a form. What if someone changes the form and sends with some inputs missing? You should count on this...

Answer (score 1):

you are looping through `$a` array has 3 items

try this solution

```
$a[0] = $_SESSION['ID'];
$a[1] = $_SESSION['firstname'];
$a[2] = $_SESSION['surname'];

$b = count($a[0]);

 for ($i = 0; $i<$b; ++$i){
     $id = $_SESSION['ID'][$i];
     $fname = $_SESSION['firstname'][$i];
     $sname = $_SESSION['surname'][$i];

$query = "INSERT INTO orders(id, firstname, surname) VALUES('$id', '$fname', '$sname')";


if (mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
}
}
```